# find in string values of characters and create a substring

Tags: c#, string, substring, arrays

in my opinion it is a common scenario

the string is something like :

```
"this is my story, if it's interesting somemail@domain.com so thanks for your time"
```

i need to make it somthing like

```
"this is my story, if it's interesting  so thanks for your time"
"somemail@domain.com"
```

my code for now is trying to count **Down** from the index of the "@"
so it is less times to check within the iteration of the for loop

```
        public string formatResultContentAndEmail(string source)
        {
            char[] Str2CahrArr = source.ToCharArray();
            var trgt = source.IndexOf('@');
            var stepsBack=0;
            for (int i = trgt; i >0; i--)
            {
                var test = Str2CahrArr[i];
                if (Str2CahrArr[i].Equals(" "))
                {
                    stepsBack = i; break;
                }
            }

            return "";//<======change this when done tests
        }
```

my first problem in that try was i couldn't find when it hits a space .

but even when i'll solve that problem, is that approach is the right one ?

what is the simplest way to extract the mail substring of that complete paragraph ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps there is a better regex approach which searches real emails, this is readable and efficient:

```
string text = "this is my story, if it's interesting somemail@domain.com so thanks for your time";
if(text.Contains('@'))
{
    string[] words = text.Split();
    string[] emails = words.Where(word => word.Contains('@')).ToArray();
    text = string.Join(" ", words.Where(word => !word.Contains('@')));
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/3LVcYa)

```
this is my story, if it's interesting so thanks for your time
somemail@domain.com
```

Comment: yep that sure looks more human, than others regex, and i guess in my case is the best to use . thanks for thinking simple.. if it is (:

Comment: and if i could I'd give you another +1 for that new(at least for me) online ide benchmarker / test environment

Answer (score 1):

```
public string[] ExtractEmails(string str)
{
    string RegexPattern = @"\b[A-Z0-9._-]+@[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9.-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9]\.[A-Z.]{2,6}\b";

    // Find matches
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(str, RegexPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    string[] MatchList = new string[matches.Count];

    // add each match
    foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches)
        MatchList[c] = match.ToString();

    return MatchList;
}
```

Source: http://coderbuddy.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/coder-buddyc-code-to-extract-email/

If you need a better regular expression pattern, you can probably find one at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: i guess i'll get more comfertable with Regex in the futere, but for now i will firstly test @Tim approach . Thanks, i sure will look in to that later on though!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be as follows, using String.split()

```
public String getMail(String inp) {
  String[] prts = inp.split(" ");
  for(String tmp : prts) {
    if(tmp.contains("@")) {
      return tmp;
    }
  }
}
```

This will break on strings with more than one email, but the fix for that should be trivial.